# Macro works for VBAProject Sheet 1 but not under VBAProject Personal

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Macro that I built with a little bit of aid and it works just like I want it to. The problem is right now I have to copy and paste the code every time in order to use it. I tried transferring it to VBAProject (Personal) and when ever I run it I receive an error based off one part of the code. I need help figuring out how to set it up into the personal.xlsb so I can use it daily without having to save it into the book I'm working in everyday. The error I receive is [Run-time error '9' subscript out of range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFfTE.png). Again I only receive that error when I move it to personal from workbook and I'm not proficient with excel so majority of my macro is reordered

```
Sub AutoAdjust()
'
' AutoAdjust Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+m
'
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cel As Range


    Columns("C:D").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("G:H").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("H:J").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("N:N").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("N1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Days Delinquent"
    Range("O1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Remarks"
    Columns("O:O").Select
    Columns("N:N").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns("K:K").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("J1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(11, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Columns("K:K").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("J1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Created Date"
    Range("N2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(TODAY()-RC[-4])"
    Range("N2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N107")
    Range("N2:N107" & lastRow).Select
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("-").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("-").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("J1" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("-").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With      

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("-")  'change Sheet2 to your data sheet
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row  'last row in Column N
        For Each cel In .Range("N2:N" & lastRow)    'loop through all values in Column N
            If cel.Value <= 3 Then                  'if cell value is less than or equal to 3
                cel.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbGreen  'color entire row with green color
            ElseIf cel.Value = 4 Or cel.Value = 5 Then  'if cell value is equal to 4 or 5
                cel.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow 'color entire row with green yellow
            Else                                        'any othe cell value i.e. cell value greater then 5
                cel.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed    'color entire row with green red
            End If
        Next cel
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem.

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.sheets("-")
```

needed to be

```
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("-")
```